# Unreal Engine 4 tutorial not working on Visual Studio 17

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

Earlier this week, I was assigned an introductory assignment for learning UE4. I am having problems doing the tutorial no matter if I copy the c++ code word for word by typing or by copying and pasting.

I have tried to follow [this](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/Programming/QuickStart/index.html) tutorial to no avail. Here is what I have so far. I'll start with the header for my first object, FloatingObject.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h0u4S.png)

Here is the actual CPP file:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5eHNP.png)

What can I do to take off the errors that arise when using the ViualMesh, CubeVsualMesh, and ConsructorHelpers objects? Also, what can I import to make all of these errors disappear?

I LITERALLY HAV NO IDEA HOW TO USE UE 4!

Here are my errors:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9Xz0.png)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: Please don't link images to code or images to errors. Instead, please include the code and errors as formatted text in the body of the question.

Comment: See [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44219810/1092820) for more information

Answer (score 1):

Starting with version 4.15, the default configuration requires that you must have additional `#include` directives when you reference most classes.  This change was made to make compilation faster. [See the 4.15 release notes for "Faster Compile Times"](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/Support/Builds/ReleaseNotes/4_15/index.html#new:fasterc++compiletimes) for more information.

Unfortunately, there are still many old tutorials & guides what don't fully reflect this change.

For instance, because you're using `UStaticMeshComponent` (without forward declaring with `class UStaticMeshComponent`), you must have `#include "Components/StaticMeshComponent.h"` at the top of that file.

For `ConstructorHelpers`, you must have `#include "UObject/ConstructorHelpers.h"`.

You'll likely need to add other `#include` directives.

---

### How do you know what to include?

When you need to use a class and forward declaring it isn't enough, go to the [Unreal Engine 4 documentation](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/index.html) and search for the class you are trying to use.

For example, searching for `UStaticMeshComponent` will bring you to [its API page](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/API/Runtime/Engine/Components/UStaticMeshComponent/index.html), and it says:

> **Include**   #include "Components/StaticMeshComponent.h"

---

### How do you know when this is needed?

In short, if you are just passing pointers to a class around, you can just **forward declare** with `class ClassNameHere` and be done with it. Otherwise, you'll need to `#include` the header file.

The "Pointer to incomplete class type" error is often times an indicator that you're missing an `#include`.